# 'sqrtl' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile a C++ code with ndk-build and I get the next error:

- 'sqrtl' was not declared in this scope

I include cmath in the source code and configure the application.mk as follow:

```
    APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
    APP_STL      := gnustl_static
    APP_ABI      := armeabi-v7a
    APP_PLATFORM := android-10
```

Searching into ndk sources, I found that sqrtl is defined in cmath, together with other xxxl functions (cosl, sinl, etc).

I don't know if missing a define or something like that.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

So you could find the functions in math.h, but according to

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/0jVfs3wCeGs

android doesn't support long double so not sure you're going to get any success using the standard headers... Could you use the plain double version?

Comment: Hi, I finally use the plain double version, it's not as precise as the long double version, but for now it works with my project. Thanks!